# Is that possible Bind Spinner Without _id Column?

Tags: android

```
public void DatabaseConn() {
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try { 
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
    } catch (IOException ioe) { 
        throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
    }  
    try {  
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
    }catch(SQLException sqle){  
        throw sqle;  
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    //SQLiteDatabase db =     SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver", null);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    //create an array to specify which fields we want to display
    String[] from = new String[]{"Driver_Name"};
    //create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    //create simple cursor adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
    //get reference to our spinner
    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.DriverSpin);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    db.close();
}
```

Is that possible Bind Spinner Without `_id` Column? any idea?

Edited : Except `SimpleCursorAdapter`, any others adapter able to do this? I mean without `_id` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) for `CursorAdapter` which is the superclass of the `SimpleCursorAdapter` you are using:

The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

So, no.

Edit:

Actually, there is a way to get around this issue. If you read carefully, it says that the *Cursor* must have a column named `_id`, which we can get by changing your query string to:

`"SELECT ROWID AS _id, someColumn, anotherColumn FROM Tbl_Driver"`

You will have to manually type out all of the columns you want though since doing `ROWID AS _id` will not work at the same time as using the wildcard `*`.

Comment: any others adapter able to do this? i mean without _id column

Comment: The `setAdapter` method for the spinner takes a `SpinnerAdapter` as it's parameter. There are several implementations available, but the only ones (included in the android source) that handle a `Cursor` require the use of the _id column.

You could always write your own implementation of the `SpinnerAdapter`, but if it's a database you are creating, it would be better to just add the _id column.